# Convert .DAT File to ASCII in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ascii, fread

I have a few .dat files from a data acquisition system that I am trying to read in Matlab.

Using the following code, I've been able to figure out that the greatest common denomenator of each .dat file is 1640, making an N x 1640 matrix, but after that, I'm lost.

```
fid = fopen('VECTOR1.DAT');
A = fread(fid, '*uint8');
length(A)
```

Any suggestions? I would be very appreciative of any help.

Comment: So you've successfully read in the data correct? Now what do you need to do? Just save it? Also, why do you want to save it as ASCII format? If you're just going to use it in MATLAB, you should save it as a `.mat`

Comment: Yes, I was able to read it in, but it's just a bunch of numbers 0-255. Should there be a way to get the numerical values of the data out of it? I guess saving it in ASCII format isn't the goal, but just being able to see the actual values.

Comment: Open the .dat file in a text editor. What's in there? What is your goal?

Comment: Well, if I open it in Notepad it's a bunch of boxes and weird characters: " 8 8 ñ" ... and so on. I'd like to have a nice table with numerical values.

Comment: Do you know how the .dat file was generated? You're sure it's supposed to be numbers? And what is the purpose of the table of numerical values?

Comment: The .dat file came from a data acquistion system. There may be some column headers that are text, but the major part of the data should be numerical values. The purpose is just to gather vibration response measurements.

Comment: Sorry, I mean what program are you going to use the columns of data in and what's wrong with the current output. Your question could use a little more information as to what the actual problem is. Like give some expected output and what you're getting?

Comment: The data acquisition system is called Adre,.. But I just want to be able to access the data in Matlab and plot it out and everything using Matlab's plotting tools. But when I read it into matlab, I get just a bunch of integers from 0 to 255.

Comment: Can you just use `load` on the file? What kind of input are you expecting anyway?

Comment: No, a load won't work. I think the data is binary. Just when I do the fread for int8 or uint16 or whatever I just get integers. I'm expecting a table of decimal values like 0.001, 0.002, ...

Answer (score 0):

The data is probably NOT `uint8` which is why you think you have gibberish when you read it as unint8.  Type `doc fread` and then try reading it in as the various types shown in the table, for example

```
figure,plot(fread(fid, 'single'));
figure,plot(fread(fid, 'double'));
figure,plot(fread(fid, 'int8'));
figure,plot(fread(fid, 'int16'));
figure,plot(fread(fid, 'int32'));
figure,plot(fread(fid, 'int64'));
figure,plot(fread(fid, 'uint8'));
figure,plot(fread(fid, 'uint16'));
figure,plot(fread(fid, 'uint32'));
figure,plot(fread(fid, 'uint64'));
```

Probably one of those will give you a better looking plot than the others.

Even better search with google for the manual for the equipment that took the data file.  That manual should tell you what the format of the data files it makes is, whether they are floating points (single or double) or integers or unsigned integers.

Comment: OK, well I've tried all of those, and haven't gotten anything that looks too interesting. I think the data is tabled with columns and rows, so I may have to do some sorting. But still when I try all those different formats, I only get integers, and I'm sure there should be some decimals and maybe even some text in there.